# Excel Index Match - How to use iferror / indexmatch

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Cell like this

```
Postcode 
2037
2009
2132
2042
2043
2048
2009
2010


Another Tab
2015
2048
2050
2006
2008
2010
2016
```

I want the result as - if the postcodes in another tab is in postcode - return 1
if the postcodes in another tab is NOT in postcode - return 0

I can't seem to figure it now...

Comment: I did this =IFERROR(INDEX(BJ_Postcode!A:A,MATCH(H5,H:H,0))0,1) but obviously its wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Index. Match will find a match or not. Try in the "Another tab" sheet

```
=if(isnumber(match(A1,Postcode!A:A,0)),1,0)
```

Adjust references to reflect your workbook.